# Redirecting error messages produced by an IF statement. UNIX Shell Scripting Basics

Tags: unix, error-handling, sh

So I've made a very basic script that utilizes getopt and if statements.

So if I type:

```
 sh MyScript -e h e
```

it will echo out:

```
  he
```

if I type:

```
 sh MyScript -o h e
```

it will echo out:

```
 eh
```

It can do this with any combination of letters. Its a very basic program with no use, but I've just started learning UNIX. Anyway, if it type:

```
sh MyScript -o
```

I will get an error message (same with if I use -e). How do I remove(or redirect) this error message?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  How do you expect us to know what to suggest if you neither show use the exact error message nor the code which might be generating it?  Actually, we really need both the code and the error message...Please learn about how to provide an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, you can always check whether the variable to which you assign values from the getopts command is empty or not, immediately after the getopts statement,

```
if [-z "${VAR}"]
then
    echo "input value null, exiting"
    exit
else
   <statements>
fi;
```

-z option is True when variable is empty and False when it's not. hope this helps

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  What you've said is helpful if the OP's script is testing variables, or using variables, without checking that they're set.  However, there's a decent chance that the problem is in the way that `getopt` (I wonder if they meant `getopts`?) is being used or invoked.  This is why I asked for more information; without seeing the code, we can't be sure what's going on.  However, here's a +1 for a good effort.